# Kotlin error DuplicateClasses 'co.touchlab.stately.HelpersJVMKt'

Tags: kotlin

I updated my Kotlin android application to version 1.8.20 and gradle gradle-8.1.1.
I have the error below.
Has anyone had this problem and can help me?

Error:
"

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class co.touchlab.stately.HelpersJVMKt found in modules jetified-stately-common-jvm-2.0.0-rc1 (co.touchlab:stately-common-jvm:2.0.0-rc1) and jetified-stately-strict-jvm-2.0.0-rc1 (co.touchlab:stately-strict-jvm:2.0.0-rc1)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

"

my dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.6'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava3:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation('com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.14.0')
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
implementation('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4')
implementation 'com.github.TutorialsAndroid:KAlertDialog:v14.0.19'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.6.1'
implementation('io.github.reactivecircus.cache4k:cache4k:0.10.0')
implementation 'com.github.DantSu:ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.yuriy-budiyev:code-scanner:2.3.2'
```

I've tried several solutions and the error still persists, I don't intend to downgrade.

Comment: Have you tried removing `jetified-stately-strict-jvm-2.0.0-rc1`?

Comment: I deleted it and it worked implementation('io.github.reactivecircus.cache4k:cache4k:0.10.0')